# Append data to existing element data without clearing div

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working with php ajax where I have to append some long html so I use html function for this job and it was working for me before.But this time when i try to append item using html function its clear all the li inside ul and then append data and if i try to append the data again its does not append li again .I cant figure out what is the main problem but i use the same way before in my code but this time its clear all the li and then append. Here is my code.

```
//UL where i have to append data
<ul class="review-list">
</ul>
```

Here is my php ajax response

```
  echo "<li>
<div class='product-comment'>
    <img src='assets\images\icons\author.png alt=''>
    <div class='product-comment-content'>
        
        <p class='meta'>
            <strong>$review_user_name</strong> - <span>$date</span>
            <div class='description'>
                <p>$review_comment</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div></li>";
```

Here is my jquery code from ajax response

```
success:function(response){
            if(response == 2){
            window.location.href = 'loginregister.php';
             
            }else{
            $('.review-list').html(response);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

By using `append()` your existing `li` Will stay and all the other data will be appended afterwards

Change your `else` To this and it will work fine.

```
$('.review-list').append(response)
```

Comment: @Azeez Are you sure your Ajax `response’ has the data you are appending ?

Comment: @Azeez can you add your full Ajax jquery code. What dataType you are using ?

Comment: Use console.log(response) to check what exactly is being returned in response.

Comment: its working buddy thnaks but before this i use html function why thats not working

Comment: @Azeez glad to hear that. Happy coding.

Comment: but my image is coming like error image why thats happen

Comment: @Azeez what is the error in image ? Are you sure img src is correct ?

Comment: @Azeez it should load images just like it’s appending the other data. I can not see any reason why not working. It should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218575/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-azeez).

Comment: @Azeez can you make sure your Ajax is set to ‘dataType: html ’ . So all the response is appended in HTML format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the append method instead of html method in your else statement

```
$('.review-list').append(response);
```